# How i can hide the folder preview image in my list treeview left menu?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list, css, style-library, view-styles

i need to hide the folder image in my list tree view on the left menu

can anyone send me the css id or class to modified the tree view since i am using firebug but i cannot find the specific style to remove the folders in my view

please help me ?